# Explaining the source of funds for a bulk deposit; Would it help get a higher visa approval rate?

Tags: visas, uk

I will be applying for a UK visit visa on the second week of December and obviously I am on the process of gathering all the needed documents to get the visa approved.

I have gone through the list of requirements and paper works.

Talking about 6 months worth of bank statements.The bit I am a little worried about is my bank statement in July.  What I did was that I have saved cash manually since March 2017 and have done a bulk deposit of the money I have gathered for 5 months (March-July Manual Savings). Source of funds is from employment and the money sent by my husband monthly. I have the money transfer receipts.

Now, do I have to throughly explain via the application form of how I got the funds bulk deposited in July? Or do I just leave it as it is.

The bank account has regular money deposits from my employer which will coinside with my pay slips.

Your thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Not *really* a duplicate, I think, because the question is how to document the legitimate nature of such funds.

Comment: - o.m. i think you laid my query right. That's what I want to know.

Comment: Explain everything. Be honest. Provide strong truthful evidence. I think these are the three pillars of visa applications.